# ようとしなかった and するとしなかった

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> その馬は立ち止まって動こうとしなかった。
>
> その馬は立ち止まって動くとしなかった。

What's the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first sentence is natural and makes sense. 「**Volitional** Form + としなかった」 indicates 過去の拒絶/過去の強い否定の意思 (past unwillingness or refusal). A few examples:

> - やめろといったのだが、彼らはどうしてもやめ**ようとしなかった**。
>     I told them not to, but they would do it anyway. <sub>(from Taishukan's Genius E-J Dictionary)</sub>
> - 彼は一部始終を話そ**うと**は**しなかった**。
>     He wouldn't tell the whole story. <sub>(from Obunsha's Lexis E-J Dictionary)</sub>

So your first sentence means:

> その馬は立ち止まって動**こうとしなかった**。
>   "The horse stopped and *wouldn't* move."

---

And.. your second sentence その馬は立ち止まって動**くとしなかった** sounds incorrect, I'm afraid. 「**Dictionary** Form + とする」 explained in [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34138/9831) is used in the forms such as 「そろそろ出かけるとしよう。」「さあ、出かけるとするか。」「そろそろ行くとする｛わ、よ etc.｝。」「さあ、始めるとするか。」 etc., meaning "I should get going (now)." "Shall we get going (now)?" "Let's start (now)." etc, but we don't use it in the negative and/or past tense form (×「動くとしなかった」×「出かけるとした」×「出かけるとしない」×「出かけるとしなかった」×「始めるとしなかった」 etc.)

Answer (score -1):

The first example is stating a lack of an attempt to action, while the second is a simple statement of a lack of action. It is all about describing intent vs just describing action/inaction.

> 馬は動こうとしなかった The horse did not attempt to move.
>
> 馬は動くとしなかった The horse did not move. The horse did not show any sign of moving.

A helpful answer to a similar post can be found [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/).