# What does the phrase "としなかった" mean in this context

Tags: grammar

車は動こうとしなかった=the car wouldn't move(according to Google translate)

Comment: Essentially the same as [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56430/45489). It treats as if a car has a will. However much the subject tried, it wouldn't move.

Comment: This is also parseable as the negative of the basic `[VERB]`ようとする form, where the `[VERB]` is in the volitional form, like しよう or たべよう -- the basic meaning is "to try to `[VERB]`".