# What is the function of the と in といきましょう

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 「うふふ、そうですねぇ、せっかくですから直接対決**と**いきましょう。士織さんもステージで何かやってくださいよぉ」

What is the function of the bold と? Is it short for と言って?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34138/9831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This と is "a quotation-like と" (I don't know the proper name) described in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68132/5010). と is not just for what someone said or thought; it can broadly mark the "content" of an action. The closest English equivalent would be "like ～", but in this case "go head-to-head" might be enough. This ～と行くか is a casual/colloquial expression used when someone has decided to "go for" something. It takes a (non-suru-verb, ordinary) noun.

- さあ、ラストスパートと行くか。
  Now, let's go for the last part.
- 次は日本酒と行きますか。
  Okay, let's try *sake* next.

Of course と行く can mean "to go with [someone]", too.

- 彼と行きたいです。
  I want to go (together) with him.

Comment: ラストスパート seems to come from "last spurt", instead of "last part"?

Comment: @EddieKal TBH I'm not sure how to use "last spurt" in English... Feel free to edit.