# Specific use of the particle と: 高みの見物といきますか

Tags: grammar, particle-と

What is the meaning of the particle と in the following sentence?

> 高みの見物といきますか

To me, it sounds a bit like に, but I can't understand it properly.

Comment: Related: [What is the function of the と in といきましょう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/80204/what-is-the-function-of-the-%e3%81%a8-in-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86)