# The emphasis of using the volitional form

Tags: volitional-form

I've come across this sentence:

> 脅かそうとしてたのか？

First, I'd like to verify that おどかそう here is the volitional form and not something like [そう](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86).

If that is indeed the case, then I've been wondering how the sentence would change (if at all) if it used 脅かす instead of 脅かそう.

For context (Spoilers for それでも歩は寄せてくる chapter 39):

> [image]

How does the emphasis or nuances of the sentence change if it was written as:

> 脅かすとしてたのか？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/what-is-the-difference-between-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%a6%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%bf%e3%82%8b-and-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b/19043#19043

Comment: The dictionary form there simply makes no sense. It's not a question of emphasis or nuance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

脅かそう is indeed the volitional form of 脅かす. If "to try/attempt to surprise (me)" is the intended meaning, you **must** use a volitional form before とする. Always.

- [JLPT N3 Grammar ようとする (you to suru)](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-you-to-suru-meaning/)

脅かすとする is totally different. It's an uncommon, colloquial version of 脅かすことにする meaning "to decide to surprise". For this usage, see: [What does verb+とする mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34137/5010) This pattern is seldom used in the past tense, and "Was this because she had already made a decision to surprise me?" makes no sense in this context, anyway.

Comment: Please beware the linked site (JLPT Sensei), it is regarded as an unreliable resource to study according to [this post in meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2196/32952). Not to say that the specific page you linked in this answer is wrong, but be warned.